# How do I inline elements in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

How do I inline elements in JavaFX?
I have the following fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Label>Input file</Label>
    <TextField maxWidth="333" fx:id="inputName"/>
    <Button text="Choose" onAction="#chooseInputFile"/>
    <TextField maxWidth="333" fx:id="outputName"/>
    <Label>Output file</Label>
    <Button text="Choose" onAction="#chooseOutputFile"/>
</VBox>
```

However the Input file, TextField, and Button all appear on different lines. Can I make them all on one line?

Comment: if is no inline vertically It is for `aligment="CENTER"` attribute  in VBOX tag  change its value to CENTER_LEFT . Now , if  you want everything on horizontal line use `HBox` instead

Comment: The whole point of `VBox` is to layout each of its children vertically, one after the other. If you don't want that behavior, then don't use `VBox`. For horizontal layout, see `HBox`. Note you can nest layouts (e.g., have an `HBox` as a child of a `VBox`, where the `HBox` has its own children). If you want a grid-like layout, use `GridPane`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HBox instead of VBox. HBoxes are used to arrange the elements horizontally

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
  fx:controller="com.example.HelloController">
<padding>
    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
</padding>
<Label>Input file</Label>
<TextField maxWidth="333" fx:id="inputName"/>
<Button text="Choose" onAction="#chooseInputFile"/>
<TextField maxWidth="333" fx:id="outputName"/>
<Label>Output file</Label>
<Button text="Choose" onAction="#chooseOutputFile"/>
</HBox>
```